# Talend Connecting to ODBC Source with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, odbc, quickbooks, talend

In Talend 5x, I was able to use the Generic ODBC connection to connect to an ODBC source (QuickBooks QODBC).  I was able to read and extract data fine from QuickBooks.

I see that Talend 6 doesn't have that ability to connect to Generic ODBC any longer. Can someone suggest an example, workaround or alternative to be able to connect to a Windows ODBC source?  I see the JDBC connection - is there an example somewhere I can see if it will do the same thing?

Thanks in advance,

HL

Comment: Have you tried this: http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/383/76/how-can-qodbc-driver-work-with-the-java-odbc-bridge-product

Answer (score 0):

odbc support was removed in Talend 6.0
Presumably, you could rollback to Talend 5.x and Java 1.7.  Or, look in the Talend Exchange 3rd-party components for an odbc component.

https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=46670

Answer (score 0):

In Talend 6x you can use tJDBCConnection and the other components that start with tJDBC to make a connection with ODBC. It's a built in Java driver for ODBC.

Comment: Can you explain how this is done? I see no other mention of this online.